# R: Matrix Combination with specific number of values

Tags: r, combinations, permutation

I want to make all combinations of my Matrix.
Ex. a binary 5 X 5 matrix where I only have two 1 rows (see below)

Com 1:

```
1 1 0 0 0   
1 1 0 0 0    
1 1 0 0 0  
1 1 0 0 0   
1 1 0 0 0
```

Com 2:

```
1 0 1 0 0  
1 1 0 0 0  
1 1 0 0 0  
1 1 0 0 0   
1 1 0 0 0
```

.
.
.

Com ?:

```
0 0 0 1 1  
0 0 0 1 1  
0 0 0 1 1  
0 0 0 1 1  
0 0 0 1 1
```

I tried using `Combination` package in `R`, but couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Can you show us your attempts?

Comment: Thereare 5 choose 2 = 10 possibilities for each row. That means your output will be a list of 100,000 matrices of size 5 x 5. Is that what you want?

Comment: @Rohit unfortunately Yes.. Exactly Right. I tried to make all possibilities matrices at once, But fail because of my memory. So, now i find solution that make matrix gradually.

Comment: @BenAvery Hello, I made possibility vector (1, 1, 0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1, 0, 0).... and tried combination with these vectors,, But failed..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `RcppAlgos` (I am the author) we can accomplish this with 2 calls. It's quite fast as well:

```
library(tictoc)
library(RcppAlgos)

tic("RcppAlgos solution")

## First we generate the permutations of the multiset c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
binPerms <- permuteGeneral(1:0, 5, freqs = c(2, 3))

## Now we generate the permutations with repetition choose 5
## and select the rows from binPerms above
allMatrices <- permuteGeneral(1:nrow(binPerms), 5, 
                              repetition = TRUE, 
                              FUN = function(x) {
                                  binPerms[x, ]
                              })
toc()
RcppAlgos solution: 0.108 sec elapsed
```

Here is the output:

```
allMatrices[1:3]
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    1    0    0    0
[2,]    1    1    0    0    0
[3,]    1    1    0    0    0
[4,]    1    1    0    0    0
[5,]    1    1    0    0    0

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    1    0    0    0
[2,]    1    1    0    0    0
[3,]    1    1    0    0    0
[4,]    1    1    0    0    0
[5,]    1    0    1    0    0

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    1    0    0    0
[2,]    1    1    0    0    0
[3,]    1    1    0    0    0
[4,]    1    1    0    0    0
[5,]    1    0    0    1    0


len <- length(allMatrices)
len
[1] 100000

allMatrices[(len - 2):len]
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    0    1    1
[2,]    0    0    0    1    1
[3,]    0    0    0    1    1
[4,]    0    0    0    1    1
[5,]    0    0    1    1    0

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    0    1    1
[2,]    0    0    0    1    1
[3,]    0    0    0    1    1
[4,]    0    0    0    1    1
[5,]    0    0    1    0    1

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    0    1    1
[2,]    0    0    0    1    1
[3,]    0    0    0    1    1
[4,]    0    0    0    1    1
[5,]    0    0    0    1    1
```

Answer (score 0):

The code I've written below worked for me. A list of 100,000 5x5 matrices. Each of the rows has two places set to 1.

```
n <- 5 # No of columns
k <- 2 # No. of ones
m <- 5  # No of rows in matrix

nck <- combn(1:n,k,simplify = F)
possible_rows <-lapply(nck,function(x){
  arr <- numeric(n)
  arr[x] <- 1
  matrix(arr,nrow=1)
})

mat_list <- possible_rows
for(i in 1:(m-1)){
  list_of_lists <- lapply(mat_list,function(x){
    lapply(possible_rows,function(y){
      rbind(x,y)
    })
  })
  mat_list <- Reduce(c,list_of_lists)
  print(c(i,length(mat_list)))
}
```